# Unknown Encoding Format

Tags: encoding, md5

My friend challenged me to figure out what encoding he used and only gave me the hint MD5 (Its not just an MD5 hash, but I'm still only learning about encryption), to which I eventually lost, but he still won't tell me what he used.

He has code that is authenticating his encoding is genuine each time, so I was hoping I could ask someone here what encoding was used and how effective it would be for me to learn about it and use it in some of my future applications.

Here are a few samples of the `String` that he is using to authenticate against:

```
pkG5llUrdxRcfe2wYLFawQ==
Zy6mwGZ9cNk3UyHvVOqpWg==
SdG3KvuLp/902XTiSlM+NQ==
mutGi6BcdPvv/z6j1B3/KQ==
pkG5llUrdxRcfe2wYLFawQ==
FJy+7HiRVlbsjntIign+PQ==
tYa63Ko4SS9WaGMUTdSkFg==
tgVrNGfztjS8Tony9swqUw==
XrhfcKqnNlPBtH8hXswEDA==
v4H+13J+Eh1ERpsGSIHYdQ==
+AV1IoAyU8DkTv6Ry+GH+g==
```

If someone could tell me what these are, I would really appreciate it.

Also, as a *bonus*, because this clearly isn't driving me crazy enough, why are there two equal signs at the end of each encryption? Is that some sort of format, or are they there just to distract me?

EDIT: A point I would like to make is that I know the original message, but I don't understand how the one message can create unique hashes every time.

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this needs to be closed?

Comment: Various cryptographic functions use fixed block sizes. Base64 for example pads the result with equal signs if the result is not of the desired width. It might be base64 is just the first step to the entire algorithm

Comment: the question is not really suited for StackOverflow I'm afraid... please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Khez Why is it not suited to SO? Its about digital-encoding, which is exclusive to programming and I'm asking what the encoding is. Its a practical question and I didn't know it didn't have an answer. Isn't this a place to learn that?

Comment: @Khez I thought it was tough, but I didn't know it was impossible to figure it out. I guess I just have to give it up.

Comment: making me feel bad now... let's continue in the chat room you posted in the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looks like raw md5 results base64 encoded... but really it could be anything, there is no way to know from looking at 16 bytes to see what produced them or if they even make any sense.

If these are all the result of the same 74 byte message, then that most likely means [HMAC-MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-MD5) used with different keys. It's not reversible regardless.

Comment: When I decoded the results from base64, it gave me a non-sensical response, so I figured it couldn't be base64. I guess I just won't ever know!

Comment: @RileyE the result of decoding the base64 is a raw md5 result supposedly

Comment: Oh. So its not the string representation, but rather the byte data?

Comment: @RileyE Yes, md5 is 16 bytes, and each and every example gives a result of 16 bytes so this is why I am assuming md5

Comment: Okay. Well, since its seemingly impossible to reverse and solve, I guess there isn't another option. I would like to see if someone else may have insight as well. Thanks you!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22849/discussion-between-rileye-and-esailija)

Comment: @RileyE I think you won't get more than what Esalija answered. You should accept his answer.